# Function for list, give me the item at position x

Tags: list, haskell

I want to create a function in haskell, that gives me the item at position x.

For example:

```
   [1..10] `give` 3    => should give me 4
```

In java this is no problem, but how can I handle this in Haskell

```
    give :: [b] -> Integer -> Maybe b
    give ????
```

Comment: `give` can't give you `3` if it provides a `Maybe b`.

Comment: It was only a typing error. Thanks ;) Now it is correct!

Comment: It can't give you 4 either.

Comment: Did you try using the `!!` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, it works for me.

```
give :: [b] -> Integer -> Maybe b
give [] _ = Nothing
give (x:xs) 0 = Just x
give (x:xs) index = give xs (index - 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain a lil bit more pls! ;) I don't know how can I write the correct function

Comment: Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
    In the second argument of `(!!)', namely `index'
    In the expression: list !! index
    In an equation for `safeIndex':
        safeIndex list index = list !! index

Answer (score 2):

I tend to avoid explicit recursion when possible. Function composition results in a more readable code, and composing standard library function results in a reliable code. So here's my version:

```
import Data.Maybe

give :: [a] -> Integer -> Maybe a
give xs n = listToMaybe $ drop n xs
```

Explanation: `drop n xs` drops the first `n` elements, so `drop 3 [1..5]` returns `[4,5]`. `listToMaybe` returns `Nothing` for an empty list, and `Just x` for `(x:_)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another fun solution in addition to those above:

```
give xs n = head $ iterate tail xs !! n
```